# Bounded quantifier and it's meaning

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

It's explained in Velleman's `how to prove` book that $\exists x \in AP(x)$
means that there is at least one value of x in the set A such that P(x) is true.

Then they go and define this logical form in one of the following pages:

$\exists n \in N(x = n^2 )$

Instead of `P(x)` here where something is true or false, how can I think about that for an assignment statement $x = n^2$ ? For all the values of `n` in the set `N`, there will be some value of `x` anyway.

Comment: That is not an assignment statement.  It is an assertion that $x$ and $n^2$ are numerically equal, which is a statement that is either true or false.    Mathematics does not have assignment statements.

Comment: The equality is not an assignment, it is a comparison.  $x$ is either equal to $n^2$ or it is not.  Thus $x=n^2$ is either true or false.

Comment: @MJD Thanks, can you post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=n^2$ is not an assignment statement.  It is an assertion that the expressions $x$ and $n^2$ have the same value. This is a statement that is either true or false, depending on the values of $x$ and $n^2$.

Mathematics does not have assignment statements.  $=$ in mathematics is always a comparison, never an assignment.  It is like the `==` operator in the C, Python, or Java programming languages, not like the `=` operator in those languages.